# Magento 2: Translation is not working in html template using data-bind

Tags: magento2, template, knockoutjs, language, translate

I have inserted the string to translate into the `app/i18n/lg_lG.csv` file.
I run the command to deploy static files, clean cache, but the string is not translated.
The string is located in this file:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/cart/shipping-estimation.html:12:
    <p class="field note" data-bind="text: isVirtual ? $t('Enter your billing address to get a tax estimate.') : $t('Enter your destination to get a shipping estimate.')"></p>
```

The magento verion is 2.3.1 .

Comment: In case if you want to try extension for translation https://magecomp.com/magento-2-google-language-translator.html

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command

```
rm-rf /var/view_processed pub/static/frontend/Vendor/Custom_theme/lg_lG/js-translations.json

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f lg_LG

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Visit **js-translations.json** file in browser.

Visit your site.

Comment: it doesn't work!

Comment: I manually edited the js-translations.json file! If it is deleted I replace with the old one and it is done!

Comment: it doesn't work as the file name is js-translation.json and not js-translations.json

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `text:` with `i18n:`, this is the translation binding although I don't know how that will work with your inline logic. IMO that is more suited to being in the JS file.

See https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/ui_comp_guide/concepts/knockout-bindings.html#i18n for more info